# Can I define a function inside ViewModel and call from Controller in EXT JS

Tags: extjs

Current scenario is I have data manipulation function inside a class and I call this function when I get data from REST service inside my controller loadData function. Then I update the store of my viewModel.

Now I was wondering Is their a way by which I can concentrate the data manipulation function and store update to view model and from controller I call viewmodel function pass the data from rest service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define `function` inside of [`viewmodel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) and call from [`controller`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ca3)**, I have created a demo using view-model and controller. I hope this will help you or guide you to achieve your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MYDEMO',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('FormController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.formcntr',
            //this will fire on get data button tap
            onGetDataButtonTap: function (btn, e, eOpts) {
                this.getViewModel().doGetData();
            },
            //this will fire on set data button tap
            onSetDataButtonTap: function (btn, e, eOpts) {
                this.getViewModel().doSetData();
            }
        })

        Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
            alias: 'viewmodel.myViewModel',
            //For setting data inside of viewmodel or somthing diffrent  opetraion
            doSetData: function (data) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'doSetData method of ViewModel, called from Controller/view');
                //set data from here
                //or you can put your logic here whatever you want
                //Depend on your requirement
            },

            //For getting data inside of viewmodel or somthing diffrent  opetraion
            doGetData: function () {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'doGetData method of ViewModel, called from Controller/view');
                //return data from here
                //or you can put your logic here whatever you want
                //Depend on your requirement
            }
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Users Profile',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            controller: 'formcntr',
            viewModel: {
                type: 'myViewModel'
            },
            tbar: [{
                text: 'GET Data',
                handler: 'onGetDataButtonTap'
            }, {
                text: 'SET Data',
                handler: 'onSetDataButtonTap'
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```